# Any readymade CSS pack for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, css, pack

Hi I was wondering if there is any ready made CSS pack for using in ASP.NET application. Something that would add styles to different ASP.NET controls in the webpage instead of me writing the CSS myself or linking the styles with controls explicitly.

Maybe something that also comes with some jQuery stuff as well. Thanks.

Comment: checkout twitter bootsrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Bootstrap is cool. But it will be no fun to use it with asp.net webforms.

Comment: @Jan really?  I'd think it would work ok ...

Comment: @dbaseman: I have no experience, but i guess the typical webforms developer doesn't want to work to much with client side html/javascript. And i don't know how you want to integrate the bootstrap controls with the asp.net controls.

Comment: Bootstrap looks good, but doesn't it work with HTML controls? Is there something that works with asp.net webforms?

Comment: @CRM Junkie You can adapt most frameworks (like Bootstrap) into an asp.net webforms project by carefully crafting your markup. Use the `CssClass` property and avoid the OOB styles in VS.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap works with asp.net webforms.
It works on css selectors. In asp.net you have the `CssClass` class. 
So all you do is assign Bootstrap classes to `CssClass` of the asp.net control.
When you get a bit advanced, you can start handling events on the client side rather then using Postbacks to the server e.g. Why bother with a Postback when getting totals for a numeric column in a Datagrid or Dataview when you can use JavaScript assigned to a html button then can traverse through the rows and calculate the total.